# Why are ArcGIS 10.2 Color Ramps missing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, color-ramp

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 Trial and found that there is no Color Ramps. Is it a bug or a restriction?

[image: I've found a similar question but without the answer but screenshot is the same]

Comment: This same question (and the same image) was asked in an ESRI forum 3 years ago. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/45169-ArcMap-10-No-Color-Ramp-Scale-Bars-and-North-Arrows

Comment: Yes, but there was no answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

first make sure that your esri style is enabled.

1. go to layer properties
2. right click on any symbol and choose
3. properties for all symbols.
4. select the style references...
5. ensure that at least one of the style references is enabled.
   [image]

You can manage the esri installed and your own style files from the style manager.
Go to customize > style manager.

[image]

you can drag and drop from any of the esri installed style (just enable it and it will be listed here) into your profile style (see [localdrive]/user/myname/appdata/)

[image]

Comment: if this is not the case you probably need to run the install again and repair.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a Win7 Computer go to:

C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates

and either delete or rename the normal.mxt

ArcMap will take a bit longer to open next time (has to recreate that mxt) but the color ramps and styles will reappear.

Comment: it worked for ArcMap 10.3 as well

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, but then I tried the Repair Option in the Installer and that fixed it finally.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include explanation as to how to apply the suggested answer, and what it does.  Please [edit] your answer to include the steps required to run the "Repair Option"

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by closing the arcmap and later deleting the NORMAL.MXT file. When I reopened the ArcMap the color ramp had returned. Thank you very much GeoGhost.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment on another answer?